# Full charge capacity much much lower than design capacity?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I had no idea about battery report on windows until recently. I have a Dell Inspiton 5570 bought 2 years ago. I didn't know if full battery capacity met design capacity then. But now, full charge capacity seems to be much much lowered. Full charge capacity is 9542 mWh while design capacity is 41998 mWh?

Here are some images. [installed batteries tab on battery report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV8Be.png)

[recent uses tab on battery report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4RCy.png)

[Battery Capacity History tab on battery report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57pIj.png)

Comment: Your battery is 2 years old.  Reduced charge capacity is a known sign of Li-ion battery aging/degradation.  See https://electrek.co/2018/05/04/are-you-killing-your-lithium-batteries/

Comment: isn't 2 years quite soon? If so, is replacing the battery is the only solution or is there something I can do with existing battery.

Comment: *"isn't 2 years quite soon?"* -- Did you read the article? How have you treated this battery?  If you have not cared for and tried to extend battery life, then you have probably unintentionally used the battery in a manner to shorten its life.  Your battery is not dead yet, but the "typical" lifespan of a laptop battery is reportedly about 2 to 4 years.  Considering the hazards of Li-ion batteries, do not try any rejuvenation ideas.

Comment: Yes, I read the article and I don't think I did anything that would degrade the battery so quick. My laptop always was on room temperature (not so high). If we are talking about laptop getting heat up while using, it definitely happened few times. I used to use laptop like at least 8 hours a day, still do,  because I was trying learn web develoopment. That part was mostly internet surfing nothing much heavy on processor. Yeah, I did play pubg and clash of clans using bluestacks at times like for around 3-4 months.

Comment: Instead of describing how you have treated your *battery*, you focus instead on *laptop usage*.  *"Nothing much heavy on processor"* is irrelevant to battery life.  Again, you have probably unintentionally *used the battery* in a manner to shorten its life. Beside overheating, you may have drained the battery and/or performed many charging cycles.

Comment: yeah, that did happen!!